# Why is logrotate not running automatically?

Tags: cron, logrotate

I have set up a Syslog-ng server with some filters to split certain traffic into different files.  I modified the logrotate file located at `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng` to rotate these files daily, but logrotate doesn't run as expected.  I have to manually rotate the logs with `sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng`

I can't find the reason why it's not running automatically.

Contents of the /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng file (the section i added is the very top block):

```
/var/log/wlc /var/log/userid /var/log/cltolt040 /var/log/ise /var/log/vg /var/log/firewall /var/log/steelhead /var/log/syslog /var/log/f5 /var/log/switch /var/log/router 
{
        su root root 
        rotate 14
        create 0755 ics ics 
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty

        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        endscript

}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
/var/log/error
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

Contents of crontab:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Contents of /etc/cron.daily/logrotate:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
    [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

I was thinking it could be a permissions issue, but if that was the case wouldn't running logrotate -f also fail?

Comment: Curious: Why are doing `su root root` when logrotate runs as root b y default? And why are you applying all those options to  `/var/log/syslog`? Especially the `create` option!

Comment: I added su root root while troubleshooting this issue, I don't know if it's actually needed.  What's wrong with applying them to /var/log/syslog?  Is that file special?  I tried adding the create option so the "ics" user doesn't have to constantly use sudo to grep the logs.

Comment: It's the general log file. If you want to let a user read logs, add them to the `adm` group instead of changing modes and ownerships of the logs. Most logs are under the `adm` group by default precisely for this reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the recommendation.  So for my Syslog-ng config, would it be better to send the syslogs to a new file instead of Syslog file?

Comment: So in /etc/logrotate.conf it looks like it runs under the root:syslog group.  Could this be an issue since the actual log files are owned by root:adm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like I got this fixed.  I tried to run logrotate on the conf file instead of the syslog-ng file, `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf` but it was throwing this error `Ignoring /etc/logrotate.conf because of bad file mode.`  Did a quick search and found that this could be because of file permissions.  I changed permissions on the file `sudo chmod 644 /etc/logrotate.conf` and ran a test by changing the daily time in /etc/crontab.

The files were then rotated automatically.  So looks like this was the fix.  Thanks for the help.