# Why logrotate is not running automatically in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, cron, logrotate

I am on ubuntu 16.04 but from recent time I have seen complaints of very low system space. I tried to find and found that it was due to `old log files` so I find that the old files can be rotated as by this

`sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate`

and then manually delete it using **Bleach-bit**.
So I tried to find the reason why it is not running automatically and come across this

[Why is logrotate not running automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847790/why-is-logrotate-not-running-automatically)

and tried to open the logrotate in the editor by 
`sudo nano /etc/cron.daily/logrotate` and found the below output

```
# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
    [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

and then from here got hints to open the `/etc/logrotate.conf` and found there is something monthly specified and changed it to daily.

```
# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    daily
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    daily
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

But still nothing changed. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You remembered to restart the logging daemon to load the changed config?

Comment: @user535733, I didn't do anything except the above mentioned. How can I  restart the logging daemon ?

Comment: A reboot will do it. Other methods are mentioned in `man rsyslogd`

Comment: @user535733, actually it's not working have to manually rotate the logs with this command here `sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate`

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Have you let it run a complete cron.daily cycle since reloading the new config? What are your clues in syslog?

Comment: @user535733, well I am using `bleachbit` to delete the logs. And trying daily running it , around 200mb is cleaned, when right now i run the above command, 19 gb of data is freed.

Comment: Then you have a more important problem than log rotation - your system is desperately trying to tell you about 19 gb worth of serious problems each day. Fix the real problems, which will reduce your log size. Your logs will begin to autorotate when your disk has enough space when cron.daily runs.

Comment: @user535733, I am not sure what serious problems you are trying to mention. Can you be specific what can I have look at then ?

Comment: Asking how to read your logs is an entirely different question...and probably the question you should be asking.